# Pytorch: TypeError: get_val_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given face recognition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, face-recognition

I have a pretrained model along with different testing datasets. I want to test the model on dataset but i am unable to do so. I have no idea why i am getting this error.

**Code**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import sys
from vit_pytorch import ViT_face
from util.utils import get_val_data, perform_val, perform_val_deit, buffer_val, test_forward
from IPython import embed
import sklearn
import cv2
import numpy as np
from image_iter import FaceDataset
import torch.utils.data as data
import argparse
import os


DEVICE = torch.device("cuda:0")
DATA_ROOT = '/home/cvpr/Documents/ms1m-retinaface-t1/'
with open(os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'property'), 'r') as f:
    NUM_CLASS, h, w = [int(i) for i in f.read().split(',')]

model = ViT_face(
    image_size=112,
    patch_size=8,
    loss_type='CosFace',
    GPU_ID=DEVICE,
    num_class=NUM_CLASS,
    dim=512,
    depth=20,
    heads=8,
    mlp_dim=2048,
    dropout=0.1,
    emb_dropout=0.1
)

model_root = '/home/cvpr/Documents/Backbone_VIT_Epoch_2_Batch_20000_Time_2021-01-12-16-48_checkpoint.pth'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_root))

TARGET = 'lfw'
vers = get_val_data('/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval/', TARGET)
for ver in vers:
    name, data_set, issame = ver
    time = test_forward(DEVICE, model, data_set)
    print(time)



# -b 128 -w 0 -n PVTV2 --head ArcMarginProduct --outdir ./results/FPVT_112_8_8 --epochs 1
# def parse_arguments(argv):
#     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#     parser.add_argument('--model',
#                         default='/home/cvpr/Documents/Backbone_VIT_Epoch_2_Batch_20000_Time_2021-01-12-16'
#                                 '-48_checkpoint.pth',
#                         help='pretrained model')
#     parser.add_argument('--target', default='lfw,cfp_ff,cfp_fp,agedb_30,calfw,cplfw,vgg2_fp', help='')
#     return parser.parse_args(argv)
#
#
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     main(parse_arguments(sys.argv[1:]))
```

**Utils.py**

```
def get_val_data(data_path):
    lfw, lfw_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'lfw')
    cfp_ff, cfp_ff_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'cfp_ff')
    cfp_fp, cfp_fp_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'cfp_fp')
    agedb_30, agedb_30_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'agedb_30')
    calfw, calfw_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'calfw')
    cplfw, cplfw_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'cplfw')
    vgg2_fp, vgg2_fp_issame = get_val_pair(data_path, 'vgg2_fp')

    return lfw, cfp_ff, cfp_fp, agedb_30, calfw, cplfw, vgg2_fp, lfw_issame, cfp_ff_issame, cfp_fp_issame, agedb_30_issame, calfw_issame, cplfw_issame, vgg2_fp_issame
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/test_forward.py", line 39, in <module>
    vers = get_val_data('/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval', TARGET)
TypeError: get_val_data() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: You're not showing the code that produces the exception (*util.utils.get\_val\_data*), although the message is pretty clear: you're passing 2 arguments (strings) to a function that only expects 1. Try: `vers = get_val_data("/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval")`.

Comment: @CristiFati 20 seconds please

Comment: You passed two arguments: `'/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/eval/'` and `TARGET`, but the `get_val_data` only accepts one argument.

Comment: @CristiFati why it gives now? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cvpr/Documents/OPVT/test_forward.py", line 41, in <module>
    name, data_set, issame = ver
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)?

Comment: That's a different issue. Apparently you are using some code, but you're not sure what it does. Use *print* (e.g. `print(vers)`) before a line triggering an exception, to see how can you handle data.

Comment: There are seven dataset and i am doing evaluation through this code. print(vers) prints big matrix with dataset name and configuration. https://github.com/zhongyy/Face-Transformer/blob/main/test_forward.py